# crash in uitableview cell on scrolling

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

i facing crash when i scroll uitableview and then try to add new item in uitableview' input array

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    if([selected_table_string isEqualToString:@"table_for_category"])
    {
       [cell.contentView addSubview:[self tab_label:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[AppDelegate.category_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] fram:CGRectMake(10, 3, 200, 25)]];

        if([AppDelegate.selected_category_arr_item containsObject:[AppDelegate.category_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]])
        {
           [cell.contentView addSubview:[self img_name:@"chk_box_chk.png" frm:CGRectMake(140, 3, 30, 25)]];
        }
        else
        {
           [cell.contentView addSubview:[self img_name:@"chk_box.png" frm:CGRectMake(140, 3, 30, 25)]];
        }
    }

    else if ([selected_table_string isEqualToString:@"table_for_shape"])
    {
        [cell.contentView addSubview:[self tab_label:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[AppDelegate.shapeNames_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] fram:CGRectMake(10, 3, 200, 25)]];

        if([AppDelegate.selected_shapeNames_arrr_item containsObject:[AppDelegate.shapeNames_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]])
        {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self img_name:@"chk_box_chk.png" frm:CGRectMake(140, 3, 30, 25)]];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self img_name:@"chk_box.png" frm:CGRectMake(140, 3, 30, 25)]];
        }


    }
    else if ([selected_table_string isEqualToString:@"table_for_color"])
    {
        [cell.contentView addSubview:[self tab_label:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[AppDelegate.color_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] fram:CGRectMake(10, 3, 200, 25)]];

        if([AppDelegate.selected_color_arr_item containsObject:[AppDelegate.color_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]])
        {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self img_name:@"chk_box_chk.png" frm:CGRectMake(140, 3, 30, 25)]];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self img_name:@"chk_box.png" frm:CGRectMake(140, 3, 30, 25)]];
        }

    }
    else if ([selected_table_string isEqualToString:@"table_for_purity"])
    {
       [cell.contentView addSubview:[self tab_label:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[AppDelegate.purity_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] fram:CGRectMake(10, 3, 200, 25)]];

        if([AppDelegate.selected_purity_arr_item containsObject:[AppDelegate.purity_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]])
        {
           [cell.contentView addSubview:[self img_name:@"chk_box_chk.png" frm:CGRectMake(140, 3, 30, 25)]];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self img_name:@"chk_box.png" frm:CGRectMake(140, 3, 30, 25)]];
        }

    }
    else if ([selected_table_string isEqualToString:@"table_for_Fluo"])
    {
        [cell.contentView addSubview:[self tab_label:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[AppDelegate.Fluo_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] fram:CGRectMake(10, 3, 200, 25)]];

        if([AppDelegate.selected_Fluo_arr_item containsObject:[AppDelegate.Fluo_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]])
        {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self img_name:@"chk_box_chk.png" frm:CGRectMake(140, 3, 30, 25)]];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self img_name:@"chk_box.png" frm:CGRectMake(140, 3, 30, 25)]];
        }
    }
    else if ([selected_table_string isEqualToString:@"table_for_Cut"])
    {
        [cell.contentView addSubview:[self tab_label:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[AppDelegate.cut_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] fram:CGRectMake(10, 3, 200, 25)]];

        if([AppDelegate.selected_cut_arr_item containsObject:[AppDelegate.cut_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row ]])
        {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self img_name:@"chk_box_chk.png" frm:CGRectMake(140, 3, 30, 25)]];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.contentView addSubview:[self img_name:@"chk_box.png" frm:CGRectMake(140, 3, 30, 25)]];
        }

    }
    else if ([selected_table_string isEqualToString:@"table_for_myselection"])
    {/////IT'S RECIEVED FOR MYSELECTIONS......
        //ParcelDetails *obj_parcel_selected_for_mail;
        obj_parcel_details_for_mail = [AppDelegate.mySelected objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //cell.textLabel.text = [AppDelegate.mySelected objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",obj_parcel_details_for_mail.parcelId];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Tahoma" size:18.0];


        UIButton *mail_to_Button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [mail_to_Button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mail_icon_9"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        mail_to_Button.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
        mail_to_Button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 3);
        mail_to_Button.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.8;
        mail_to_Button.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0;
        [mail_to_Button addTarget:self action:@selector(send_mail_Action) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [mail_to_Button setFrame:CGRectMake(530,15,40,40)];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:mail_to_Button];
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Any particular message when the crash appears?

Comment: not message it directly shows main.m class

Comment: Dipak put some more relevant code and error message

Answer (score 0):

You are adding subviews to your cells every time they are shown and you are, eventually, running out of memory (that's probably why you don't get an error message or crash). To fix this, the solution that comes to mind is to tag your subviews on creation in your `img_name:frm:` method like this.

```
subview.tag = 100;
```

and inside your cell customization code;

```
 for(UIView *view in cell.subviews){
   if(view.tag = 100)[view removeFromSuperview];
 }
```

edit* The same should be done for your UIButton.

Comment: why remove before re-adding? Why not reusing them?

Comment: Well that was just the first thing that came to mind, and probably the easiest for him to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Before updating the Datasource of the TableView just call the `[yourTableView reloadData];` This should solve your crash while scrolling and updating your datasource array.